# I can't set a php cookie

Tags: php, html, web

I made a php script that allows me to switch the language of my website and for that, I used a cookie called lang to store the user's language prefer but I don't Know why this cookie can't be set as I can't find it in the chrome developer tap .. Although I made this script also with session variable in case cookie isn't set, it doesn't work either, as it shifts the language whenever I change the page

this is my PHP script

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lan = $_GET['lang'];
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lan;
    setcookie("lang", $lan, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30), '/');
  } else if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lan = $_SESSION['lang'];
  } else if (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lan = $_COOKIE['lang'];
  } else {
    $lan = 'en';
  }

  include "languages/" . $lan . ".php";
?>
```

I have two files in that language folder en.php and ar.php and each one contains an array with translation like below

```
<?php
$lang = array(
  "Give" => "Give",
  "Blood" => "Blood",
  "Register as a donator" => "Register as a donator",
  "Search for a donator" => "Search for a donator"
```

I include my script in all my site's pages 
[here is my chrome developer tap screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6qZo.png)

any thoughts?

Thanks for helping in advance :)

Comment: According to your code if this `isset($_GET['lang'])` is `false` then the cookie wont be set.

Comment: it was true when I tested it

Comment: Suggest making a "test script" with no conditions, to set the cookie. That way you can rule out a browser setting forbidding cookies.

Comment: I did and it didn't work :)

Comment: Well thats a start in terms of setting a cookie in a test script without conditions  `I did and it didn't work`. So now, we need to determine why this is so. It's a start because if cookies are not being set, then that needs to debugged before conditions are in place

Comment: Could you include in your question on where you read the cookie? As a prelim debug measure, could you include *all* the code at and before you read the cookie? I say this because there may be a requirement where there can be no output before the reading of the cookie, plausible but I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: I've just tested your code on my Host applying some echos between the ifs and both the session and cookie were created. I am left with the honourable conclusion that your form could be having but POST as method